# Как первым написать от имени сообщества в вк

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, не могу разобраться с сообщениями сообщества в ВК.
[Документация по messages.send](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send) говорит, что

> Нельзя первым писать пользователю от имени сообщества

К тому же это невозможно сделать в веб-форме для отправления сообщений из сообщества.

Но при этом существуют такие сообщества-боты (например, [Бот Максим](https://vk.com/bot_maxim)), которые сразу при вступлении в группу пишут тебе. Как они это делают? Как настроить это?

Comment: Ну в веб-форме вы используете токен доступа принадлежащий текущему пользователю, а не сообществу. Про то что нельзя первым писать от имени сообщества - не нашел на странице

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Бот, приведённый вами в качестве примера, в реальности не пишет первым, если просто *подписаться* на сообщество.

С октября прошлого года ВКонтакте позволил [сообществам первым писать пользователю](https://vk.com/dev/blog/community-messages). Но не всем подряд, а только тем, кто *явно* изъявил желание, подписавшись на сообщения сообщества. Сделать это можно несколькими способами.

1. В веб-интерфесе на странице сообщества в меню «Действия» выбрать пункт «Разрешить сообщения».
   [image: Меню действий]
2. Выполнить API-запрос [messages.allowMessagesFromGroup](https://vk.com/dev/messages.allowMessagesFromGroup).
3. С помощью виджетов «[Разрешить писать сообществу](https://vk.com/dev/AllowMessagesFromCommunity)» или «[Сообщения сообщества](https://vk.com/dev/CommunityMessages)»
4. Если пользователь уже начал диалог с сообществом, то он будет получать сообщения пока не откажется от этого самостоятельно.

В первых трёх случаях бот получает событие **message_allow** через [Callback API](https://vk.com/dev/callback_api), в последнем — событие **message_new**.

<sup>На основе информации с [официальной страницы администрирования сообществ ВКонтакте](https://vk.com/page-59800369_51260649).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Второй раз столкнулся с тем, что получаю сообщение от сообщества, в котором даже не состою и решил посмотреть повнимательнее, как именно это сделали [Coca-Cola Россия](https://vk.com/cocacola) и [Лис](https://vk.com/mindblowing_stories).

**На самом деле, первое сообщение сообщества идёт не как сообщение, а как подарок.**

Кстати, для пользователей тоже нет ограничения на подарки в том плане, что их можно посылать кому угодно, даже если просто написать этому человеку ты не можешь.